# Responsive templates and search bar

Tags: search, responsive

I am working on a pretty basic website and I have the search bar exactly how I want it to look. The problem is that I cannot get the search button to be responsive to different devices. On my iPhone 6, the button moves below the search bar and doesn't look right. Any thoughts on how I can get this better looking? I am new to responsive templates!

Comment: See this example: [link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/clearfix/)

Answer (score 0):

Try clear fix:

```
<div class="bg-info clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary float-left">Example Button floated left</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary float-right">Example Button floated right</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciate your help.